# python dataframe and plotly draw with unevenly spaced time series

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly

I have a data like below

[image]

I need to draw a graph like below with dataframe and plotly python. Note that the x-axis's time label is unevenly spaced.

[image]

I can draw with below code, but I can not label the time at the right position. I do not need the index label on x-axis.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go


fig1 = go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['value'], marker_color='rgb(255, 0, 0)')
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it right to draw like this?
[image]

```
data = [
    {"index": 1, "time": 1, "val": 7000},
    {"index": 2, "time": 1, "val": 6000},
    {"index": 3, "time": 2, "val": 7800},
    {"index": 4, "time": 3, "val": 8600},
    {"index": 5, "time": 3, "val": 8300},
    {"index": 6, "time": 3, "val": 8700},
]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['time-index'] = df['time'].astype(str) + df['index'].astype(str)
plt.plot(df['time-index'], df['val'], label='c1')
plt.show()
```

Comment: It's partly right. But I do not want the index to appear on the graph because they are too big value. Only the time should appear with grid like in my post.